# If between dates 1 and 2 respond Green. If between dates 3 and 4 respond Blue

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I cannot figure out how to expand my formula. I have it returning the answer "Green" if it falls between two dates (columns B and C). I want to add onto so if the date does not fall between B and C but does fall between D and E, it will return "Blue" instead. If the date falls out side of BOTH date ranges the standard FALSE will due. Here is what I currently have:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use nested `IF`'s so instead of

```
..."Green", FALSE)
```

Replace the false with another `IF`

```
=IF(AND(A2>=B2, A2<=C2), "Green", IF(AND(A2>=D2, A2<=E2), "Blue", FALSE))
```

Comment: That is perfect and easy to understand so that i can edit ranges and such without getting lost. Thank you! ill credit the answer as soon as it lets me.